# What is the worst-case big-O time complexity for this code?

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

I had a quiz in my class and didn't do so well on it. I'm looking to find out if someone can explain to me what I did wrong here - our professor is overwhelmed with office hours as we moved online so I thought I'd post here.

```
def functionB(n):
  for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range(i,6):
      n = n // 2
  return n
```

I gave the following answer:

> The above function is O(n^2) because of the nested for-loops. Although
>   the value of n is being cut in half upon each iteration, it does not
>   have an impact on the actual run time of the code.

I was given 3/10 for it but unfortunately there is no explanation so I'm unsure of what I got wrong and why. Is there anyone here who can explain the correct answer to me?

Comment: I think question should be posted on [cs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) instead.

Comment: @Carcigenicate okay, that makes sense. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman Sorry. Thank you for the link and I will ask there next time.

Comment: @DMellon, its ok! but there are many network in stackexchange for multiple things, this one is just for code issue/problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're considering `n` to be the argument passed in, note how you say

> it (`n`) does not have an impact on the actual run time of the code.

If `n` has no impact on the runtime, it wouldn't be `O(n^2)`, since that indicates that the runtime scales (quadratically) with `n`.

This function looks like it's `O(1)`. The function will always run exactly the same, regardless of input. It will always run exactly 15 times, because `n` has no bearing on how many times the loop will run. The runtime of the program is decided entirely by the hardcoded arguments given to `range`, which never change.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! I will supply it with a check mark as soon as the time limit is met.

Answer (score 0):

The approach suggested by @Carcigenicate is correct. Here I will add something to it.
The time complexity of code snippet is O(1) i.e. constant time. If I take both range bounds inclusive in nature then it will run exactly for 21 times (6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1). So the return from the method would be n/2^21. So in the bitwise concept, we can say the given number has been right-shifted 21 times if we are considering remainders i.e. n is decimal number.